# frequency and percent gene in combined list

Tags: python, python-3.x, bioinformatics

```
frequencies = {}

with open('GBM_Fusion_List.txt') as fileIn:
    line = fileIn.readline()

    while line:
        line = line.split('&')
        fl0 = frequencies.get(line[0],0)
        fl1 = frequencies.get(line[1],0)
        if fl0 == 0:
            frequencies[line[0]] = 1
        elif fl0 > 0:
            frequencies[line[0]] = fl0 + 1
        elif fl1 == 0:
            frequencies[line[1]] = 1
        else:
            frequencies[line[1]] = fl1 +1
        line = fileIn.readline()

for key, value in frequencies.items():
    print('{}\t{}'.format(key,value))
```

This is a problem I've been struggling with. I'm new to python and started a new internship.

Write a python script to count frequency and percentage of each partner gene in a fusion gene.

```
GeneA&GeneB
GeneA&GeneC
GeneD&GeneF
.
.
```

The output includes names and frequency of gene and its partners and a percentage of each partner.

Example output:

```
GeneA   2   GeneB   1   50% GeneC   1   50%  
GeneD   1   GeneF   1   100%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help, I've tried to make it simple to understand

```
frequencies = {}
with open('GBM_Fusion_List.txt') as file:
    rows = file.read().split()
    for fusion_gene in rows:
        first_gene, second_gene = fusion_gene.split('&')
        if first_gene in frequencies:
            frequencies[first_gene]['count'] += 1
            partner_genes = frequencies[first_gene]['partner_genes']
            if second_gene in partner_genes:
                partner_genes[second_gene] += 1
            else:
                partner_genes[second_gene] = 1
        else:
            frequencies[first_gene] = {
                'count': 1,
                'partner_genes': { second_gene: 1}
            }
    for frequency in frequencies:
        print('{first_gene} {first_gene_count}'.format(first_gene=frequency,first_gene_count=frequencies[frequency]['count']), end='')
        gene_occurance = 0
        for _, freq in frequencies[frequency]['partner_genes'].items():
            gene_occurance += freq
        for  gene, freq in frequencies[frequency]['partner_genes'].items():
            percentage = ( freq / gene_occurance) * 100
            print(' {gene} {freq} {percent}%'.format(gene=gene, freq=freq, percent=percentage ), end='')
        print()
```

Comment: Thank you so much that was really helpful!